# Issue with RTKQuery's dynamicBaseQuery not extending endpoint's url

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

Hi I am currently trying to add RTK Query into my code base, with splitting endpoint files and dynamic baseUrl. I followed the doc: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#constructing-a-dynamic-base-url-using-redux-state and below is what I have so far:

```js
// baseApi.ts
const rawBaseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: "http://my-base-url/",
})

const dynamicBaseQuery: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  const projectId = getProjectId();
  const projectVersion = await getProjectVersion(); //here is an async that fetches the version from the BE
  const adjustedUrl = `${projectId}/api/${projectVersion}`;
  const adjustedArgs = typeof args === 'string' ? adjustedUrl : { ...args, url: adjustedUrl };

  return rawBaseQuery(adjustedArgs, api, extraOptions);
}

export const baseApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "base-api-reducer",
  baseQuery: dynamicBaseQuery,
  endpoints: () => ({}), // trying to do file split here
})
```

In a separate file, I have the injectEndpoints implemented as below:

```js
// data.ts
export const apiWithData = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getAllData: build.query<Data[], void>({
      query: () => ({
        url: `${DATA_URL_SUFFIX}?any_other_query_param=true`
      })
    })
  }),
})

export const { useGetAllDataQuery } = apiWithData
```

When I call useGetAllDataQuery in my project's Component.tsx, the browser's Network tab shows a network request with url ended at the ${projectVersion}/
The expected Network url is "http://my-base-url/projectId123/api/v1/data?any_other_query_param=true", but the actual url is "http://my-base-url/projectId123/api/v1/", and the request ended up with a 404 due to the invalid url.

Any idea what is going on? Or anything I have missed to add. I checked the `store.ts` and everything is setup following the doc as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had it solved. So the issue was that I am missing an extra step. The `args` param of `dynamicBaseQuery` are actually coming from the endpoints. I need to wrap that up with my `adjustedUrl`, so it would look something like:

```js
const dynamicBaseQuery: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  const projectId = getProjectId();
  const projectVersion = await getProjectVersion(); //here is an async that fetches the version from the BE

  // Updates
  const endpointUrl = typeof args === 'string' ? args : args.url;
  const adjustedUrl = `${projectId}/api/${projectVersion}/${endpointUrl}`;
  const adjustedArgs = typeof args === 'string' ? adjustedUrl : { ...args, url: adjustedUrl };

  return rawBaseQuery(adjustedArgs, api, extraOptions);
}
```